# How do you remove the root CA certificate that fiddler installs

Tags: ssl, certificate, fiddler

Fiddler helpfully offers to add a unique root CA certificate to intercept HTTPS traffic.

Once this certificate has been added, how do you go about removing it?

[image]

Comment: This also removes all the other interception certs that bog down my VPN client!!!

Comment: And break the cisco client

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Since Fiddler 4.6.1.5 the GUI is a bit different.

[image: Fiddler Options]

Go to Tools -> Fiddler Options -> HTTPS. Then click the "Actions" button and then "Reset All Certificates"

It will popup a message that it could take a while but it's really quick. Approve all popups and there you go.

Pay attention not to re-approve the certificate again (when I did it the message for approving the certificates popped up when I finished to approve all the popups.)

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to first deselect the "Decrypt HTTPS traffic", then choose "Remove Interception Certificates"?

Comment: Yes, no need for that

Comment: I wonder how "Remove Interception Certificates" is related to this.

Comment: @Stephen I unchecked "Decrypt HTTPS traffic" and selected "remove interception certificates" and that worked for me.

Comment: I'm on v5.0.2#####.#####, and `Reset All Certificates` simply generated a new one. It didn't prompt to delete the old until I unchecked `Decrypt HTTPS traffic` and then ran `Remove Interception Certificates`

Answer (score 91):

Either of two ways:

1) Disable HTTPS decryption and click the button titled "Remove Interception Certificates"

[image: fiddler options dialog]

2) Open CertMgr.msc, open the Personal and Trusted Stores, and use the Delete key on the root.

Comment: How do you do this in Windows 8 for m #2?

Comment: @MikeFlynn: It's not really clear what you're asking. The procedure in Windows 8 is the same as everywhere else.

Comment: Actually the naming is different but I figured it out.

Comment: @MikeFlynn: The "naming" of what? Windows 8 is my primary OS.

Comment: Eric, After following the step 1, I can see in certmgr.msc that personal certificates installed by fiddler are removed though I can see a fiddler certificate in "Intermediate certificate authorities" section. Do I need to remove that manually? Bug?

Comment: Fiddler's certificate shouldn't ever appear within "Intermediate certificate authorities"; you should be able to simply delete it.

Comment: @EricLaw This option seems to have disappeared in the newest version of fiddler, and the replacement option [seems to be disabled](http://imgur.com/O2XJiNG). Any thoughts?

Comment: @JMK: The option was merely moved. The menu item, like its button predecessor, is disabled until you uncheck `Decrypt HTTPS traffic`.

Comment: @EricLaw seems to be a bit buggy on Windows 10

Comment: @JMK: Comments are a poor a support forum, and your response isn't actionable anyway. Happy to chat; click Help > Fiddler Discussions.

Comment: The 2nd step is useful especially if you uninstalled fiddler without removing the certs first.

Comment: Is it safe to use this feature of Fiddler? Why are the certificates called `DO_NOT_TRUST_fiddlerroot` ? Is that an inside joke?

Comment: The point of naming the CA root `DO_NOT_TRUST` is to communicate to anyone who doesn't know why they're seeing it that they should not trust it. People who know why they're seeing it (Devs deliberately using Fiddler) can trust it if they want.

Answer (score 9):

In Fiddler go to `Tools` » `Options` » `HTTPS`.
Then uncheck `Decrypt HTTPS traffic` and run `Actions` » `Remove Interception Certificates`.

This will remove all Fiddler certs from the Windows certificate store.

[image]

**Background:**
Fiddler is obviously using a kind of white hat "man in the middle" approach to decrypt and inspect any HTTPS traffic. To do that, it needs its own certs to be trusted. Therefore leaving `Decrypt HTTPS traffic` checked but removing the Fiddler certs as proposed in other answers does not make a lot of sense, as Fiddler can't decrypt then anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Just expanding on EricLaw's 2nd option, which is more useful if you've put that cert on multiple devices (fairly common during network testing), and you only want to remove it on one (source - http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler):

1. Go to the Security tab in settings
2. Tap Trusted credentials, then select the User tab
3. Tap on the Fiddler “Do not trust” certificate, then scroll down to remove it
4. You may need to power cycle your device to get all apps to forget about the Fiddler certificate (e.g., the Chrome browser will continue to try to use it for a while)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the procedure with `Progress Telerik Fiddler Classic` in its version `v5.0.20211.51073`.

1. Go to `Tools` > `Options` > `HTTPS`. The option to `Remove Interception Certificates` is greyed out, because `Decrypt HTTPS traffic` is still toggled ON.
2. Untick the box in front of `Decrypt HTTPS traffic`. You should be able to `Remove Interception Certificates`.

In the end:

- Fiddler Classic's root certificate has been removed.
- Fiddler-generated Certificates have been removed.

---

To ensure that certificates related to `Fiddler` have been effectively removed, in accordance with the messages displayed above, you could browse through authorized certificates with the following procedure.

1. Click on `Open Windows Certificate Manager`.

NB: if you prefer to use Windows' built-in tools, e.g. if Fiddler has been uninstalled,

1. Press `Win+R`, type `certmgr.msc` in the search box, then press `Enter`

Then:

2. Go to `Action` > `Find Certificates...`
3. In the search box for `Contains:`, type `DO_NOT_TRUST_FiddlerRoot`
4. In the drop-down box for `Look in Field:`, ensure that the option is set to `Issued By`. If the option were set to `Issued To`, you would find fewer matches.
5. Click on the button `Find Now` to list every certificate .

In my case, there was one Fiddler-related certificate left after the procedure. If that is the case for you as well, then you may want to manually delete it, by right-clicking on this entry.