# nodejs "npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN"

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm new to nodejs and npm. I'm trying to install log4js and this is the command for the install:

```
npm install log4js
```

I'm running this from Windows Command Line and I after a while of a marker spinning I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "log4js"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

npm ERR! self signed certificate in certificate chain
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\srv\npm-debug.log
```

I tried doing `npm config set ca=""` like suggested here: http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78085451721/npms-self-signed-certificate-is-no-more but I'm still getting this error.

How can I solve this and install NPMs ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [receiving error: 'Error: SSL Error: SELF\_SIGNED\_CERT\_IN\_CHAIN' while using npm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626990/receiving-error-error-ssl-error-self-signed-cert-in-chain-while-using-npm)

Comment: I had this issue due to a corporately installed product called websense.  It was hijacking the certs.  removal of the `virus` solved the problem

Comment: For mac OS users, i answered this on another thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72926171/8145332

Answer (score 281):

> Disabling strict-ssl mode will remove this error.
> `npm set strict-ssl false`

Since this is turning off SSL security, we should try this as last step if below two steps don't help.
This issue can arise due to incompatibility between SSL certificate file of npm and node registry.
Try
1) telling your current version of npm to use node's ca instead of built in ca
`npm config set ca=""`
2) OR upgrading your version of npm

`npm install npm -g --ca=null`

Comment: Solved even my issue. All I have to run it as super user ;-)

Comment: @geoidesic It worked inside docker file for me. Try this command with RUN before npm install.

Comment: This is an insecure approach, making you vulnerable to MITM attacks. 
The proper solution is to find the actual certificates used and added them to your npm cafile.

Comment: This fixed my issue : npm set strict-ssl false

Comment: @Tarun what is the version of npm you are using?

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain my npm version is 6.13.4

Comment: Would be worth adding that you should re-enable strict-ssl after install is complete.
`npm set strict-ssl true`

Comment: Reality of working in BigGlobalCorp is that we have to resort to this because InfoSecurity do MITM attacks all the time, it makes them feel more secure ;)

Answer (score 85):

I had the same problem on windows 10.

open windows powerShell and enter the following command:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Then you can use:

```
npm install [your package]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Setting strict-ssl to false is dangerous. Thanks for solving this headache.

Comment: I am still getting that error post running this cmd.Help!

Comment: This solved my issue, however it is not clear what the implications are if you change the https by the http in the registry configuration. Doesn't it has the same effect as setting the ca to null?

Comment: this solution is no different from setting npm set strict-ssl false.
using http (without s) is prone to man in the middle attacks

Answer (score 22):

As metioned by Akshay Vijay Jain above,

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

**TURNING OFF SSL BEFORE INSTALLING THE LATEST VERSION**:

[image: TURNING OFF SSL BEFORE INSTALLING THE LATEST VERSION]

Then install the latest version

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

**INSTALL SUCCESS!!**:

[image: INSTALL SUCCESS!!]

See the screenshots added for clarity.

Answer (score 20):

While setting StrictSsl to false is an option, it compromises your npm security. I recommend not disabling it. The following instructions elaborate on Shreedhar's post to use the cafile. Though it's written from a Windows 10 machine perspective it can be adapted.

Our company uses SSL Inpsection via a proxy, so at the very least we need to include the SSL Inspection certificate. The following instructions assume you are able to use a modern web browser on the machine you are trying to use an externally reaching npm function.

1. From a command console, run the following: `npm config list`
2. Record the value for metrics-registry. This should be a URL.
3. Open a browser to the URL. As of writing this answer, it is https://registry.npmjs.org/
4. Open the certificate information for the site. For Chrome on Windows, this involves clicking the padlock icon to the left of the URL in the address bar and selecting the option *Certificate*.
5. Inspect the certification path. For me, there is our corporate CA and our SSL Inspection certificate.
6. Download each certificate as Base64 encoded into a .cer or .crt file.
7. Compile all the certificates as-is into one .cer or .crt file.
8. Place this file into a user folder. Though we have a network-based users folder I recommend and use a local machine based folder. Note the full path to this file.
9. From a command console, run the following: `npm config set cafile "C:\Local\Path\To\cafile4npm.cer"` modifying the path and file noted in step 8.
10. Run your `npm install` command.

Comment: I have never used docker images but maybe I can help out. What are the details of the error you are receiving?

Comment: there's no extra details; same error as in the title of the OP.

Comment: How do I do this part? Download each certificate as Base64 encoded into a .cer or .crt file. When I open the Certification Path there's no option to download? Must be installed right? My problem is a real unsigned cert exists in node_modules.

Comment: Thx. Running npm config list revealed a global /usr/local/etc/npmrc with a cafile=... entry which ruined my day until I found this answer. Thx.

Comment: @JohnPeters If you click the padlock icon to the left of the URL Address Bar, there should be an option to view the certificate(s). In Windows 10, the window that pops contains 3 tabs: General, Details, and Certification Path. While the Certification Path tab shows you all the certificates between you and the server, it is from the Details tab that you can download the file. On Windows 10, the button is Copy to File...

Comment: I did find the root cause of this issue, someone had put an unsigned cert into a node module via a test component. Angular 8 and 9 couldn't deal with it.  When we went to Angular 10 this problem went away, most likely due to an upgrade of those node modules causing the issue.  Moral of story was "Don't ever publish an unsigned cert."

Comment: How do you "compile all the certificates as-is into one .cer or .crt file"?

Comment: @Kyrstellaine it means you have to copy all the strings into one file. If you have say 2 certificates in the chain, your final file that is referenced in the configs should have both the strings.

Answer (score 19):

I'm new to npm as well.  Besides the commands mentioned in your link I tried the following and it resolved my issues:

- npm set strict-ssl false
- disabled McAfee temporarily

Reference: [Npm SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099098/npm-self-signed-cert-in-chain-on-azure)

Comment: Disabling SSL should never be the answer.  There must be some workaround for this...

Comment: @AndrewLandsverk it is if you are behind a restrictive corporate firewall.

Answer (score 6):

Was getting same error when executed via Docker build.
Powershell execution, however, was error free. Then modified the dockerfile with following (as suggested above):

RUN npm config set ca=""

RUN npm set strict-ssl false

This fixed the cert chain issue.

Comment: Confirm, that's resolved my issue too. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In CentOS and other Linux distros you need to configure NPM to use your Certificate Authorities file:

```
npm config set cafile "/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem" -g
```

Obviously check the file exists and contains all CA Roots you may encounter (e.g. corporate proxy).

Answer (score 4):

solve this problem with this command

```
npm config set strict-ssl=false
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP?

Answer (score 3):

**As of February 27, 2014, [npm no longer supports its self-signed certificates](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78085451721/npms-self-signed-certificate-is-no-more).** The following options, as recommended by npm, is to do one of the following:

**Upgrade your version of npm**

```
npm install npm -g --ca=""
```

-- OR --

**Tell your current version of npm to use known registrars**

```
npm config set ca ""
```

**Update:** npm has posted [More help with SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN and npm](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/78165272245/more-help-with-self-signed-cert-in-chain-and-npm) with more solutions particular to different environments

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626990/receiving-error-error-ssl-error-self-signed-cert-in-chain-while-using-npm)

Answer (score 2):

Did you also tried settings `cafile` accommodating all pems in one file? [npm add root CA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788564/npm-add-root-ca)

If you use proxy in your `.npmrc` file, I will suggest to set `no_proxy` environment variable with value of your `<server IP address>`

Answer (score 2):

You can disabled certificate validation for TLS connections:

`NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 npm install puppeteer`

Answer (score 2):

Our corporate environment inflicted this on us via some company cert chicanery, and this bit the Windows devs in both npm and git operations. For npm, the instructions provided previously by gregsonian (building a cert and pointing npm config to use it) still work well. (Win-10 for reference.) I prefer otherwise keeping SSL enabled.

Comment: Upvoted solely on your use of the word "chicanery".

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had installed Fiddler, which has a self signed certificate which made the npm install go crazy.

See here how to remove the self signed Fiddler certificate [How do you remove the root CA certificate that Fiddler installs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827901/how-do-you-remove-the-root-ca-certificate-that-fiddler-installs)

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above helped out my situation.  The culprit turned out to be the package agent-base pre 6.0.1.  Indeed the owner admitted to shipping out self-signed certs in a test folder of his package.  This forced a reinstall -D and -g but problem is still happening.

I found this cert by searching node_modules folder for *.pem.

Still working on getting npm caches to listen to me.  Of course I'm the dummy right?

I'll post back additional findings.

**Solution Found**

7/7/2020

Our Angular application was upgraded from 8.3 to 10.0 today.  Guess what? The errors disappeared. The root cause was someone published an unsigned cert that made it's way too deep in the NPM modules library.  Even NPM 6.15 had it!

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solutions here and none really worked for me. I tried updating npm but got either a timeout (when registry was set to http://registry.npmjs.org/), or a 403 Forbidden responce (when registry was set to http**s**://registry.npmjs.org/)

In the end, realsing that my problem was caused by being behind a proxy, what *did* work for me in the end was:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

(credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12832637/4191296)

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled node js and angular cli. It started working !!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trust another certificate I think its better define the environment variable to trust the new certificate
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=<path to .pem file>
https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I initially setup squid to proxy all http & https requests on my local ubuntu box, but was not aware that TLS version >= 1.3 requires ssl-bump, peek and splice TLS handshake features.

The following might help others understand what is going on "under the hood" so you can be confident that your fix is correct. If you don't use squid then skip that part, but take note of the final npm step.

Here are the steps to upgrade squid :

1. Install an upgrade patch [provided by diladele](https://github.com/diladele/squid-ubuntu) . I also ran : apt upgrade after apt update
2. Use [this tutorial](https://elatov.github.io/2019/01/using-squid-to-proxy-ssl-sites/) to upgrade squid config to compliment the new ssl-bump features
3. Add env vars HTTP_PROXY=http://your.proxy.domain:3128 HTTPS_PROXY=http://your.proxy.domain:3128
4. Setup Firefox and/or Chrome to use squid as the http/https proxy

To enable npm ssl install, add the proxy ca-certificate.pem to the npm config

5. npm config set cafile /etc/squid/certs/squid-ca-cert.pem

After running step 5, npm install from https://registry.npmjs.org worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I was blocked by my company Certificate to resolve the problem I followed the steps as Gregsonian said but the problem was not resolved for me for different reasons:

- Make sure you get the root ca file or as it was said by Gregsonian, copy all the certificate into one cer file (in the correct order !)
- Make sure that you don't have ca list defined: ca=[""](if defined then add correctly the ca path in that list). Because I set my cafile with the correct cer file but since i had an empty ca list also defined, npm choose by default the list so the error kept appearing -> the solution is to remove that list then and only have the cafile (npm config set cafile "path-to-cafile")

By doing correctly the two previous steps i can now use npm correctly

Hope it can help some people