# npm ERR! Cannot read property 'path' of null

Tags: node.js, npm, nodes, npm-install, node-modules

> **C:\Users\Abc>npm install -g
>
> npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\Abc
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\Abc\AppData\Ro
>   aming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g"
>
> npm ERR! node v7.2.1
>
> npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
>
> npm ERR! Cannot read property 'path' of null
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>
> npm ERR!  https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Abc\npm-debug.log**

*i have reinstall node with version 7.2.1 
after every time this occurs when i download any package*

**need suggestion related to null path error**

Comment: which package you are trying to install??

Comment: npm install cordova -g

Comment: if you are trying with `npm install -g` obviously you'll get this error because u haven't mentioned any package name.

Comment: but "npm install cordova -g" also give same snippet

Comment: Yeah I have same problem using it in both ways - with -g at the end and before

Comment: [it solved my issue:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141153/nodejs-npm-err-code-self-signed-cert-in-chain)
npm set strict-ssl false

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue while installing gulp
My NPM and Node Versions are:

- node v7.7.4
- npm  v4.1.2

In npm version 4x, https client certificates were made required rather than optional. Details are in their github area. 
Long story short, what helped for me was running the following command:

```
 npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Once this was done, running the command

```
npm install gulp -g
```

Worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you are working behind proxy, you need to set proxy for nodejs

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy_host:port 
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy_host:port
```

Hope it Helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

npm install command is used to install packages.

**Reason for your error :**

You don't have any package.json in your current working directory.

Also, you didn't provide any package name to install from.

**Tips :**

Check out https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install for more details.

Never use -g (install dependency globally unless you intend to).