# NVM - Unable to install expo dependencies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, nvm

I am using [nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) to switch between 4.4.3 and 12.14.1 node version.
After i Switched to version 12.14.1 and tried to install expo and run react-native project as stated [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started).

```
npm install -g expo-cli
expo init
npm start
```

But while running `npm start` i am getting the below error.

```
npm ERR! code SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! errno SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm ERR! request to https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz failed, reason: 
self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

I followed the step as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141153/nodejs-npm-err-code-self-signed-cert-in-chain).

So i ran the following command.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

But i am still getting the same error.Please help!

Also i dont intend to disable strict-ssl as stated

```
npm set strict-ssl false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following command to disable strict ssl-mode and you will not get the error:

```
npm set strict-ssl false
```

Comment: Its really not safe to do so. I have read the link in the question Mayank.Also updated the question.