# npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I tried to create React app in VS Code by using below code. I got this error "npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC"
Node version: v14.18.1
npm version: 8.1.0
OS: windows 10
VS code: 1.16.0

PS D:\React-Projects> npx create-react-app first-app

Creating a new React app in D:\React-Projects\first-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
npm ERR! 10796:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bizwe\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-10-16T08_13_20_686Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting first-app/ from D:\React-Projects
Done.

I tried all solutions given in stack overflow, but none of them is worked, Anybody help me please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Type `npm set strict-ssl false` in the terminal. I have tried everything found over internet. Nothing worked until this. But watch out since this has security issue.

Read this for further info : [Fixing ssl certficate error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913941/how-to-fix-ssl-certificate-error-when-running-npm-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

**The Fix:-**

> Just change the settings of the windows defender firewall.

It applies to all operating systems like windows, Linux, MacOS.
Here is the sample in windows for checking window security
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/381vN.png)

> Make sure that in window security all are checked

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
npm ERR! 7828:error:1408F119:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:decryption failed or bad record mac:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:677:
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\CODER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-29T15_40_10_455Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

[solution to the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H8jw.jpg)

It works in my case. There are some window security issues. Please make sure that you have all green checks on the window security as well as the window firewall.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32747735)

Answer (score -1):

I hope this could help.
I use a MAC. i found out today that i was on a 3G network. I switched to 4G, ran my network speed and got to at least 4mb per seconds download speed.
It worked when i tried again, maybe you can do that.
I got a proxy error with 3G.

Follow the docs

npm create-react-app mp-app

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and I solved it by deleting my SSH key from Github (in my case) and from my machine, then I generated a new SSH key.

[Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)