# ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC - can't install node packages either via npm or yarn

Tags: node.js, ssl, npm, yarnpkg, npx

**Can't install node packages via npm or yarn**

This has been happening to me since last month and I have tried multiple solutions from the internet including stack overflow solutions like https://stackoverflow.com/a/34945326/15488503

The problem is regenerated each time I run commands like

```
yarn install
```

```
npm install
```

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

The error which I see mostly revolves around this error message -

> ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC

[image]

I have tried with multiple node and npm versions and still, the problem remains the same for me.

[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve that?

Comment: still didn't find any solution @AliIhsanElmas

Comment: I solved it today.  It was about my connection. I was using a USB WiFi adapter to connect to the internet. Instead of that, I connected via a network cable and now the error has gone.

Comment: For me, I believe it is also a connection issue. It works fine when I connect to any other wifi network than mine @AliIhsanElmas. The thing is I can't understand the reason for this.

Comment: I believe it was due to my unstable connection because I was also having some problems while downloading files using my browser. Sometimes it gave a "connection error" and stopped the download process.

Comment: For me my network was stable.

Comment: I personally use my phone to share the connection to my computers on Windows 10 and macOS. It also seems to be related only to my network, but I can not understand how to fix or why this happens

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem when i was using internet via a USB Wifi adapter. Connected my computer with a cable solved my ERR_SSL_DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC problem
¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I do something similar. I connect to another hotspot network for downloading npm packages.

Answer (score 1):

Besides updating your version of node to an active or current LTS you want to ensure your NPM registry is set to an HTTPS endpoint:

```
npm set registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that! Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

After facing the issue for more than 6 months, I think I found a solution. It's a `VPN` (virtual private network).

I realized that the issue was because of my network connection and was not a fault of `NPM`. I was using `VPN` while downloading packages, which prevented that error.

However, this also doesn't work all the time.

**Update**: Changing my network connection solved the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your Windows Firewall tries to block npm from downloading files from your connected network.

To fix this issue follow the steps below:

1. Select "*Windows Defender Firewall*" in your Windows search bar:
   [View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9lLQ.png)
2. Click on "*Allow an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall*": [View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHs7t.png)
3. Click on "*Change Settings*" button: [View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehJri.png)
4. Scroll to "*Node.js Javascript Runtime*" and make sure you select both public and private networks to allow npm to install files irrespective of your network. [View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPJjL.png)
5. Finally, click "Ok" and now try re-installing the npm package.

If this does not work then try installing the dependencies by switching on VPN.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue while using cheap USB Wifi adapter.
For me solution was to set timeout:

```js
yarn --network-timeout 100000
```

I assume if any error with connection occured, operation is not aborted but renewed thanks to this param