# Unable to download project zip file for "https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane-JS/archive/yo-office.zip"

Tags: node.js, yo

- I am trying to implement `yo generator` example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator).
- I did `npm` and `node` installation.
- While doing `npm install -g yo generator-office` I faced the same `self signed certificate in certificate chain` issue. This was solved using `npm config set strict-ssl false`.
- While doing `yo office` I am facing the same issue.
- Error

```
Unable to download project zip file for "https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane-JS/archive/yo-office.zip".
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141153/nodejs-npm-err-code-self-signed-cert-in-chain?rq=1

Comment: @FelixG tried but it is not working

Comment: have you resolved this issue? If then please publish right solution.

Comment: @user2832577 i have in the answers section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Export your certificate as below

```
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS="<certificate_path>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same Issue and got resolved by

1.Setting CA Certificate
2.Defining Environment Variable

Steps

a)Get your CA Root Certificate in .pem format
npm config set cafile /RootCertificate.pem

b)System Variable "NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS" "C:\RootCertificate.pem"

My machine is running under Zscalar